# When does the distribution change in interference/which way measurements compared to the time of the type change of the measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment, faster-than-light, wave-particle-duality

Does anyone know of any experiments that have looked at the temporal relationships of this?
Measurements that show the dual nature of the particle/wave are well known. The fundamental feature of which is that **the output distribution as a result is measurably and characteristically different.** There are several possibilities for particles/photons and if a measurement cannot determine which one is realised, an interference distribution is obtained. However, if we change the type of measurement and it is possible to determine which possibility is followed (which way measurement), the interference disappears. The result is a distribution that is consistent with the nature of the particle (e.g. double slit experiments, interferometric experiments and the other similar experiments).

The natural and important question arises in this way: **relative to the event when the which way detector is switched on** (i.e. the character of the measurement changes), **when exactly is the first change in the output distribution observed?** The issue is interesting and can be investigated if the which way detector that can be switched on is located spacelike ahead of the screen or detector that measures the output.
Unfortunately, I am not aware of any experiments or studies that answer this question, which is why I am asking on this forum.

Essentially 3 cases are possible in my opinion:

A). Only those particles/photons that have not yet passed through the ww-equipment at the point of the switch-on event will give the different distribution. Those that have already passed the ww-detector site at the time of the switch-on event are still involved in the formation of the interference pattern.

The answer in this case is that one have to wait as long as it takes for the photons or particles to travel from the detector site to the screen before there is a measurable change in the distribution.
This version assumes that the change is due to direct interaction between the detectors and the particles/photons.

B) Any particles/photons that reach the final screen or detector within the light cone of the switch-on event will already be producing the altered distribution. But those outside the light cone still form the initial interference distribution. So we imagine an unknown effect propagating at speed c, starting from the location of the ww detector when it is switched on - and the first change in the output distribution is when enough time has elapsed for this effect to reach the output screen or detector.

C) No time delay or other time dependence is observed in the change of the distributions. So immediately after we turn on the ww detector, it changes immediately; the result is a transformation from interference to particle distribution.
*The laws and known calculations of quantum mechanics are compatible of case C)* as far as I know. However strange or fantastic this possibility may seem at first sight.

It could be argued - and many people obviously think this - that version A) is "self-evident". It is true, they say, that the measurement is not described by the Schrödinger equation, but is an instantaneous "jump". But the photons/particles propagating in the device are described by a known type state function. Commonly the state function is a Gaussian-type wave packet, which travels in time and space as known from optics. So we have to wait for such a wave packet to travel with effective speed c (or slower) from the ww detector location to the final detectors, and then we can experience the change. *But in QM the state function is not a realistic material wave as in classical electrodynamics and wave optics. It is a probability wave propagating in configuration space, an essentially abstract mathematical entity. Why should the law, the limitation, that applies to classical material waves apply to such waves?* And superposition reduction is an act of the probability wave, not of the real material wave.  Surely we cannot take it for granted that it must also travel between those two points at a speed c. Such reasoning in my opinion confuses the classical material wave picture with quantum behaviour. At the moment, one can say that QM does not give any definite clarity as to which version is realised - it would have to be empirically found out.
If the experiment decides in favour of version A) or B), we would gain new information: some unknown effect would convey the reduction of the  state vector from the ww-detector, with the maximum velocity c ; e.g. we would find a trace of a kind of hidden parameter.

**A strong argument in favour of C is that when there is only one detector at a slit, the interference pattern changes in the same way as with two detectors.** But this detector does not interact with the ones going through the other slit, it does not measure them. Yet it changes where they come through the screen. Similar to other non-interacting measurements  (for example bomb test). However, if we don't need interaction, why should we stay inside the light cone?

After all, the calculations describing the measurement process do not include time as a dependent variable. Furthermore, the states of the which way detectors and the measured particles/photons are entangled; because of the measurement. *And the reduction of superposed states vector or the entangled states is an instantaneous, time-less process, both theoretically and empirically proven.*
But of course we are correct in our thinking if *we maintain the possibility of cases A) and B) being realised by some as yet unknown factors.* We can't dictate to Nature in advance how it should behave - actual experiments must decide which one will be realised (or perhaps some strange fourth possibility that cannot be formulated in terms of what we have seen so far).
Versions A) and B) are different. If they are particles, it is because they are moving in the apparatus at a speed less than c, so the light cone boundary will include some of them that have already passed the ww detector at the time of switch-on. And when it comes to photons, it is because the geometry of the experimental setups is usually such that the photons under test travel longer distances than the shortest distance (for example, in MZI they travel along the sides of a rectangle).

It is important that such an experiment is not done in a single way, but with a strong source. *So many photons/particles entering the apparatus at the same time,* which will themselves form the appropriate distributions in a continuous manner. Do not wait for them to enter the measurement and arrive at the end one after the other (as the question itself then becomes pointless). Also, the *which way detector*, whose switch-on causes a change in the type of measurement, *must be spacelike separated from the final detector or screen.* It should be located in front of the final screen or detector. Because if it is located after them (as in Wheeler's original delayed choice experiments), it is also not suitable for the time delay versus instantaneous change issue.

It could be argued that the purpose of delayed choice experiments is precisely to investigate the specific timing. Do we get any answers to these questions? Delayed choice means to study the time delay between the photons/particles passing through the slits and the ww detectors being switched on. Their essential result is that no matter when the switch on occurs relative to the previous one, it can be before, it can be after, or how much after, has no bearing on the results obtained. The interference image changes in the same way, even in cases of extreme delay. (In the Mach-Zehnder version, the delay is the time between the first beam splitter passing and the detector turn-on.) This is another temporal aspect to investigate. Our question is not about this, but about the temporal relationship between the turn-on of the ww detectors and the change in the interference image that is the final result. Thus, delayed choice does not answer our question; studying what is proposed in the paper is not superfluous; in fact, it is very necessary.

*I will describe the specific situation* for the well-known, relatively simple *Mach-Zehnder interferometer setup* to which the question applies:
Consider the MZI interferometer with two beam splitters. A ww detector can be inserted rapidly into the first half of the lower arm, which then blocks and absorbs the photons passing through it. The source is sufficiently strong so that a sufficient number of photons can be continuously and simultaneously received by the two output detectors.

Situation 1: The ww detector is outside the arm. Thus, due to phase shifts and constructive interference, *all arrive in detector D1, and none arrive in D2 due to destructive interference, i.e.  it does not signal.*
Situation 2: quickly insert the operating ww detector. Then the which way measurement is performed and the ones in the lower arm are absorbed. The photons of the upper arm split in two at the second BS and about 25% of the original intensity is already arriving at the *D2 detector, so it starts to signal.* The intensity entering in D1 is also reduced to about 25%.
So inserting a ww detector causes substantial and well measurable differences for the D1 and D2 detectors.
**Our question is how long after the ww detector is inserted do these differences appear?** The general versions A), B), C) formulated above need to be considered specifically for this. The figure shows the point. For briefness, I will highlight only one point:  [image]

If we insert the ww detector at time T0, the boundary of the light cone of this event is a spherical surface of distance c*∆t away from the detector location in 3-dimensional space. *Should we wait for this to reach the distance between the ww detector and the location of the detectors D2, D1? Or does it already happen before then that D2 is triggered and the intensity of the measured signal in D1 is reduced?*
The delayed choice measurements that I know do not answer this, because in those the change in measurement type is not achieved by an operation in the MZI arms, but by inserting or removing the second BS.

But perhaps there have been experiments that have investigated the question I have raised; or, if not intended to do so, have "incidentally" yielded the relevant data.
**I am of course aware that if version C) is confirmed, it opens the door to the possibility of FTL communication.** But I don't intend to discuss this now; it should first be found out how it happens. I also do not want to get into the complicated topic of quantum erasers and retrocausality. For the moment, I am looking for answers to the relatively simple arrangement and question above. Of course, *it is easy to formulate the same for the case of double slit experiments.* If anyone can show a meaningful measurement not for MZI but for double slit that deals with the question of time, I would also welcome a response.

Comment: What we call "particles" are actually quanta. Quanta are irreversible energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge exchanges between quantum fields and external systems (usually called "source" and "detector"). They don't have paths. Waves are emergent phenomena that are the result of many independent detections of quanta. If you make these measurements time dependent, then you are simply going to see a disappearance of interference/diffraction patterns due to time-energy uncertainty. That is a completely classical effect that can be observed easily on fs laser pulses.

Comment: FlatterMann -Your statement is certainly correct - but I don't know why it would be an answer to what I'm asking. I am asking about the time between two macroscopically measured events. One event is to insert the ww detector into one arm of the interferometer. The other event is that the D2 detector starts to signal (in the specific example I describe). What is the time between them, or does it happen immediately? How would the uncertainty relation answer this?

Comment: Basically everything in these kinds of experiments is happening at the speed of light. So if the interferometer arms are a total of 1m, then the relevant time scale is 3ns. You can reasonably stretch that on the table top scale to maybe a few hundred ns with zig-zag light paths between the mirrors. Will you ever get FTL comms? Sure. It will happen the same day a guy starts selling an actual perpetual motion machine. Both devices will make their inventors the richest men on Earth instantly.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic Could you help me answer this question? Or could you recommend an expert here whose attention it might be worth bringing it to?

Comment: There was an experiment not so long ago that indicated that wavefunction collapse is not an instantaneous process, so there is a time scale involved in measurement. On another point, I think the other delayed choice experiments out there would answer your question: no communication is happening, rather the outcome of any measurements is consistent with the other outcomes of measuring or interfering the entangled state.

Comment: @Codename47 Can you show me specifically the experiment you are referring to? It may indeed be relevant to the question, but unfortunately I am not familiar with it. As for the other commonly known delayed choice experiments, I could not find any data on the time dependence I asked about. They were not tested. They focused that the event, i.e. the change of measurement type, should be spacelike separated from the event where it should first be "decided" whether the quantons should travel as particles or waves. But the time of the change in the output result was not made the subject of measur

Comment: @Codename47 The time scale involved in a "measurement" is infinite. That this has to be so can be seen immediately from our requirement that we retain the outcome of the measurement forever. So no matter what happens in the quantum system, we want there to be an "external" and lasting change in nature. This means that some other system has to retain some part of the energy of the quantum system. In relativistic terms "a measurement event" is really a worldline with a starting point but without endpoint. I can't tell you how to make "sense" of such an ontological requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot offer any reports of the experiment you are asking for, but I can motivate why such an experiment might be considered moot in view of the currently available [delayed choice quantum eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser) experiments.

First of all, QM predicts option A. Your option C would require the WW detector to be able to affect photons which have already passed that point in space. There is no reason one would expect this to happen. The QM prediction would follow an argument of the following form: before insertion of the WW detector, the state arriving at beam splitter 2 is something like $|\psi_1\rangle = (|1\rangle +|2\rangle)/\sqrt{2} $ where 1 and 2 indicate the different paths. At $t=t_0 + L/c$, where $L$ is the length from the WW detector to beamsplitter 2 and $t_0$ is the time of insertion of the WW detector, this will change to the state $|\psi_2\rangle = |x\rangle $, where $x$ is 1 or 2 with equal probability, and no interference will happen.

In the context of quantum eraser experiments, what they find is that for a given entangled photon pair, if one photon reveals its which-way information, the other photon will contribute to the particle pattern on the other detector, i.e. will not interfere with itself. This does not necessarily require communication between the photons, it is entirely predicted and explained by the entangled quantum state.

How can we use this information to answer your question? Given the results of other quantum eraser experiments, those photons which reveal their which-way information upon insertion of the detector will be correlated with zero interference at beam splitter two. We would thus expect that the interference will stop at a time $t=t_0 + L/c$.

Comment: Thank you. It's not clear to me yet why the QM prediction would be what you wrote. As far as I know, superposition reduction is always the result of an interaction (measurement) due to an operator. What operator is it that acts with that time delay on  |ψ1⟩ and reduces it? There is no explicit time dependence in QM operators, at least in the Schrödinger picture. (A minor point, but there seems to be something written off in the formula for t, since the second term is not time-dimensional.) @Codename 47

Comment: I fixed the formula for t, thanks. The only operator involved in the measurement is a projection operator which reduces the superposition to a probability distribution. Measurement cannot be accounted for within the time evolution described by the Schrödinger equation. But you can propagate a state to the measurement device, project it and then propagate it further. The time propagation will be trivial though. If you are interested in partial measurements over finite time, you should take a look at decoherence and pure and mixed states in density matrices.